# Symfony2 admin token in public area

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm having trouble getting security to work the way I want it.

I want administration part to be protected so only people with **ROLE_ADMIN** can access it. And that works just fine. However, I want my **unprotected/public** area to be able to differentiate between **ROLE_ADMIN** and **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY**.

I can't make it work though. After I log in into admin section. I can see in toolbar that I'm authenticated and have **ROLE_ADMIN**, but as soon as I go back to public section of the website it turns into **anonymously authenticated**.

Here is security setup I currently have:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    myusername:  { password: mypassword, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login_area:
            pattern: ^/login$
            anonymous: ~

        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/admin|^/login_check$|^/logout$
            form_login: ~
            logout: ~

        public_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
```

As you can see I tried adding both **ROLE_ADMIN** and **IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY** roles to '^/' path in access control, but it doesn't change anything.

I searched both Symfony2 book and Cookbook entries but didn't find anything that would help me regarding this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, and just 20 minutes later, after digging the Symfony2 book for the third time I found this:

> Multiple firewalls don't share security context
>
> If you're using multiple firewalls and you authenticate against one firewall, you will not be authenticated against any other firewalls automatically.

It was enough to just use one firewall on '^/' pattern and set access_control to this:

```
- { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```